# How to interpret when there is two adjectives in front & end

Tags: meaning, attachment-ambiguity

> Necessary Employees and Persons Authorized

Does it mean "(necessary employees) and (persons authorized)" or "necessary (employees and persons) who are authorized"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"authorized" is not an adjective as much as it is a participle. If it were a full sentence, it would have read:

> Necessary Employees and Persons **Are** Authorized

Comment: Then does "authorized" and "necessary" apply to both "employee" and "person"?

Comment: Yes. You can read it simplified: "Necessary Personnel Authorized"

Answer (score 0):

It is ambiguous, but given the specific context, it would be *more* common for it to be treated as two things:

1. Necessary employees.
2. Persons authorized.

Part of the problem is the order of the words in the second phrase. More commonly, *authorized* would come before *Persons*:

1. Necessary employees.
2. Authorized persons.

In which case, the full version of the sentence would be more understandable:

> Necessary Employees and Authorized Persons

---

In the original version of the sentence, by having put *Authorized* at the *end* of the sentence you are creating the possibility that it applies to either just *Persons* (which is typical) or to *Employees and Persons*. But note that if *Authorized* applies to both, then it would also be possible for *Necessary* to apply to both.

---

If you really *do* want to have both modifiers apply to both nouns, then you would likely write it differently:

> Necessary and Authorized Employees and Persons

This makes it clearer that the combination of two nouns is being modified by a combination of the two adjectives.